# How to repeat php "if" 20 times?

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to repeat php "if" 20 times with `dh_c_01_01`. How I can do it?

```
if ($dh_c_01_01['id'] == $a_c_a_max) {
  $dh_sq_01_01 = $a_b_s_05;
} elseif ($dh_c_01_01['id'] == $a_c_a_1_b) {
  $dh_sq_01_01 = $a_b_s_06;
} elseif ($dh_c_01_01['id'] == $a_c_a_2_b) {
  $dh_sq_01_01 = $a_b_s_07;
} elseif ($dh_c_01_01['id'] == $a_c_a_3_b) {
  $dh_sq_01_01 = $a_b_s_08;
} elseif ($dh_c_01_01['id'] == $a_c_a_4_b) {
  $dh_sq_01_01 = $a_b_s_09;
} elseif ($dh_c_01_01['id'] == $a_c_a_5_b) {
  $dh_sq_01_01 = $a_b_s_10;
} elseif ($dh_c_01_01['id'] == $a_c_a_6_b) {
  $dh_sq_01_01 = $a_b_s_11;
} elseif ($dh_c_01_01['id'] == $a_c_a_7_b) {
  $dh_sq_01_01 = $a_b_s_12;
} elseif ($dh_c_01_01['id'] == $a_c_a_8_b) {
  $dh_sq_01_01 = $a_b_s_13;
} elseif ($dh_c_01_01['id'] == $a_c_a_9_b) {
  $dh_sq_01_01 = $a_b_s_14;
}


if ($dh_c_02_01['id'] == $a_c_a_max) {
  $dh_sq_02_01 = $a_b_s_05;
} elseif ($dh_c_02_01['id'] == $a_c_a_1_b) {
  $dh_sq_02_01 = $a_b_s_06;
} elseif ($dh_c_02_01['id'] == $a_c_a_2_b) {
  $dh_sq_02_01 = $a_b_s_07;
} elseif ($dh_c_02_01['id'] == $a_c_a_3_b) {
  $dh_sq_02_01 = $a_b_s_08;
} elseif ($dh_c_02_01['id'] == $a_c_a_4_b) {
  $dh_sq_02_01 = $a_b_s_09;
} elseif ($dh_c_02_01['id'] == $a_c_a_5_b) {
  $dh_sq_02_01 = $a_b_s_10;
} elseif ($dh_c_02_01['id'] == $a_c_a_6_b) {
  $dh_sq_02_01 = $a_b_s_11;
} elseif ($dh_c_02_01['id'] == $a_c_a_7_b) {
  $dh_sq_02_01 = $a_b_s_12;
} elseif ($dh_c_02_01['id'] == $a_c_a_8_b) {
  $dh_sq_02_01 = $a_b_s_13;
} elseif ($dh_c_02_01['id'] == $a_c_a_9_b) {
  $dh_sq_02_01 = $a_b_s_14;
}

[$dh_sq_03_01, ... , $dh_sq_20_01]
```

up to 20 times

Comment: try `switch` `case` statement

Comment: Please clarify the input structure and what you are trying to do. Chances are we can come up with better way… and it's not replacing 20 if/elses with a switch/case

Comment: It's always a good habit to give your variables proper names, something that makes sense. It will save you a lot of time later on, when revisiting the code. Writing self explanatory code also cut's back on comments, and really helps if you're asking questions, like on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure I understand your question correctly, or assume I know what your variables are or what their values are.

Based on your question, this example uses extra variables, [for loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and dynamic variables. It also assumes that each of your [dynamic variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) exists:

```
<?php
$dh_c_limit = 20; // <-- loop limit
$a_c_a_limit = 9; // <-- loop limit
$a_b_s_addition = 5; // <-- based on your question
$a_c_a_max = 0; // <-- change this to whatever '$a_c_a_max' should be!

for ($dh_i = 1; $dh_i <= $dh_c_limit; $dh_i++) {    
    if(${"dh_c_".str_pad($dh_i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."_01"}['id'] == $a_c_a_max){ // <-- checks against '$a_c_a_max'
        ${"dh_sq_".str_pad($dh_i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."_01"} = ${"a_b_s_".str_pad($a_c_i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)}; // <-- set the '$dh_sq_' variable to '$a_b_s_' variable
    }
    else{
        for ($a_c_i = 1; $a_c_i <= $a_c_a_limit; $a_c_i++) {
            if(${"dh_c_".str_pad($dh_i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."_01"}['id'] == ${"a_c_a_".$a_c_i."_b"}){ // <-- checks against '$a_c_a_' variable
                ${"dh_sq_".str_pad($dh_i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."_01"} = ${"a_b_s_".str_pad(($a_c_i+$a_b_s_addition),2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)};  // <-- set the '$dh_sq_' variable to '$a_b_s_' variable
                break; // <-- break the loop
            }
        } 
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

That is a bad habit. Try to use switch case, or use array as container

```
$array = [
  'id1' => 'action1',
  'id2' => 'action2',
   ...
];

$dh_sq_02_01 = $array[$dh_c_02_01['id']];
```

Just and example. Hope helps